# Rotate SCNVector3 around an axis

Tags: ios, linear-algebra, scenekit, trigonometry

This is probably more of a linear algebra question, but say I have a SCNVector and I want a new SCNVector that's at an angle to the original around the y axis (or any axis for that matter). So ideally:

```
extension SCNVector3 {  
    // assume dot, cross, length, +, - functions are available.
    enum Axis {
        case x, y, z
    }
    func rotatedVector(aroundAxis: Axis, angle: Float) -> SCNVector3 {
        // code from smart person goes here
    }
}
```

e.g. `(0,0,-1).rotatedVector(aroundAxis: y, angle: pi/2) = (1,0,0)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try to use quaternions https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/working_with_quaternions

```
extension SCNVector3 {
    enum Axis {
        case x, y, z
        
        func getAxisVector() -> simd_float3 {
            switch self {
            case .x:
                return simd_float3(1,0,0)
            case .y:
                return simd_float3(0,1,0)
            case .z:
                return simd_float3(0,0,1)
            }
        }
    }

    func rotatedVector(aroundAxis: Axis, angle: Float) -> SCNVector3 {
        /// create quaternion with angle in radians and your axis
        let q = simd_quatf(angle: angle, axis: aroundAxis.getAxisVector())
        
        /// use ACT method of quaternion
        let simdVector = q.act(simd_float3(self))
        
        return SCNVector3(simdVector)
    }
}
```

Use:

```
let a = SCNVector3(5,0,0)

let b = a.rotatedVector(aroundAxis: SCNVector3.Axis.y, angle: -.pi/2)

// SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 5.0)
```

Also you can rotate around any vector:

```
let simdVector = q.act(simd_normalize(simd_float3(x: 0.75, y: 0.75, z: -0.2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In general case use [Rodrigues' rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula).

> Rodrigues' rotation formula is an efficient algorithm for rotating a
>   vector in space, given an axis and angle of rotation

For initial vector **v**, rotation axis unit vector **k** and angle theta result is

**v**<sub>rot</sub> = **v** * cos(theta)  + (**k** x **v**) * sin(theta) + **k** * (**k**.dot.**v**) * (1 - cos(theta))

Comment: Is that for right handed or left handed unit space?

Comment: Emm... I always deal with right-handed with rotation angle theta - CCW against axis direction. Seems that handiness is important here for the second term that contains vector product. But it also contains sine function, so I cannot say  - whether handiness influences on result -it depends on convention about angles' direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to a [comment on gamedev.net](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/357797-rotate-a-vector-by-90-degrees/?do=findComment&comment=3348469) I think I have what I need. It doesn't work for arbitrary angles but as it turns out I only need 90° so this works for me. Here's the solution:

```
extension SCNVector3 {
    enum Axis { case x, y, z }
    enum Direction { case clockwise, counterClockwise }
    func orthogonalVector(around axis: Axis, direction: Direction) -> SCNVector3 {
        switch axis {
        case .x: return direction == .clockwise ? SCNVector3(self.x, -self.z, self.y) : SCNVector3(self.x, self.z, -self.y)
        case .y: return direction == .clockwise ? SCNVector3(-self.z, self.y, self.x) : SCNVector3(self.z, self.y, -self.x)
        case .z: return direction == .clockwise ? SCNVector3(self.y, -self.x, self.z) : SCNVector3(-self.y, self.x, self.z)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use this